# Not able to return Array to calling function, returned array having value "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, function

I am doing some database operation,

1. send the JSON to the **dataTable** function
2. using for loop, execute the all the JSON elements
3. If element exists in the database, push that *data* to the found Array
4. If not, push *"false"* to the *found* array and
5. Return to the getResults().
6. but I am getting result as an **undefined**.

**Observation**
I know where I am pushing the result is inside the function. That's why I am getting results as an *undefined* but I am a bit confused.

```
function getResults(){

var data = [
        {
            "place": "bangalore"
        },
        {
            "place": "mangalore"
        }
    ]

     var result=dataTable(data)       // calling the function dataTable
     console.log(result)              // its printing "undefined"
}

const dataTable = async (data) => {
    var found=[]                                                   //initializing the array
    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        dat = data[i]['place'];
        try {

        let sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE data =?';
        let query = await connection.query(sql,[dat], (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (Object.keys(result).length === 1) {
                found.push(url)                                 //pushing to the array every iteration
    enter code here
            }else {
                found.push("false")                             //pushing to the array every iteration
            }
        });

    }catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
  }
return found;                                              //return to the calling function
}
```

Comment: `dataTable` is an async function so it **always** returns a promise. It won't be an array but it shouldn't be `undefined` either

Comment: You're mixing async/await (promises) with callbacks. Use the promise-based version of your database library (they all have one these days)

Comment: @Phil actually we can return the array i have tried it. but here i used the connection function may be that is the problem i guess

Comment: @Phil why i am not using promise-based version of your database library means, i am completely building Synchronous way of code and i want to return the output from each function..        and can you suggest the promised based npm library, Thank you

Comment: Assuming you're using MySQL, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql